# Concatenate the result of two concatenations in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concat-ws

I have this mySQL query:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS('=>',column_1,column_2,column_3) 
AS column_union 
FROM table
```

In which the result is the combination of these 3 columns with `=>` as delimiter.

[image: table]

Is it possible to concatenate in the same query the result of the first concatenation with any other columns?

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('#**#',column_4,column_5,column_union) 
AS another_column_union 
FROM table
```

In which the final result `another_column_union` should look like this way:

```
value_column_4#**#value_column_5#**#v1=>va=>v0
```

Comment: Wrap your first query up in a derived table, then continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a view, a subquery, or repeat the expression.  It can also be simplified to:

```
SELECT concat_ws('=>', column_1, column_2, column_3) as column_union,
       concat_ws('#**#', column_4, column_5, 
                 concat_ws('=>', column_1, column_2, column_3)
                ) as another_column_union 
FROM table
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thank you for your reply. I have forgot to specify some important things in the the topic question. Take a look to the delimiter and the final result that I expect in the final concatenation query.